# Java - Variable is being accessed from within inner class

Tags: java, variables, final

IntelliJ wants me to make my variables final, but I need them to change (I will be modifying them within the method). How can I fix this issue?

Here is my code, I've never had this issue before:

```
public void openDoor(int id, int x, int y, int face, int type) {
    Server.getTaskScheduler().schedule(new Task(0, true) {
        @Override
        protected void execute() {
            ObjectManager.deleteObject(c, x, y); //Error is here
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: If I move this method to a different class it works perfectly fine... I don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to figure a clever way around it because this is a requirement in Java. You can't modify local variables or method parameters from within an anonymous inner class that are declared outside of it. One possible solution is to create a "holder" class, like:

```
class Holder {
    Object c;
    int x;
    int y;
}
```

Then have your method accept a final Holder, and the anonymous class can modify the content of the Holder. Another (ugly) option is to make each of the affected parameters an array. Then the array can be final, but, again, you're free to modify the content.

The best option is probably to stop and ask yourself why you need to modify those variables in the first place. Probably, your task execution should be returning some value instead.

Answer (score 1):

Adding another answer, because I would tend to think that the more convenient solution would be to make copies of the variables instead, kind of like this:

```
public void openDoor(int id, final int f_x, final int f_y, int face, int type) {
    Server.getTaskScheduler().schedule(new Task(0, true) {
        int x = f_x, y = f_y; /* Either here... */

        protected void execute() {
            int x = f_x, y = f_y; /* ... or here, depending on your requirements */
            ObjectManager.deleteObject(c, x, y);
        }
    });
}
```

This way, you don't have to access the data indirectly through a "Holder" object every time you want them.

Both ways are ugly, of course, but that's just Java. No way around that. :)